# Problem with Ralink Wifi Adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, ralink, adapter

I basically need to create a wifi hotspot, with a Ralink Usb Network Adapter (Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS). The results from lsusb are the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I run ifconfig, instead of wlan0 it shows wlx and a mac address.

```
wlx784476c37e2b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:44:76:c3:7e:2b  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Although I tried to setup the hotspot with the easy way (through edit connections-->new connection etc), the hotspot isn't identified by other computers at home. Where exactly is the problem and how do i fix it so that i can create a wifi hotspot? I've searched all similar problems but couldn't figure out what's going on.